# Flutter/Dart How to center sizedbox to top center of screen?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have he following code

```
return SizedBox(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.pink)),
                        height: 20.0,
                        width: 20.0,
                      );
```

I would like to know how to center this to the top center of the screen. Thank you.

Comment: wrap SizedBox with Align(alignment: Alignment.topCenter, child: ...)

Answer (score 7):

Wrap `SizedBox` with `Container` and set `alignment` property to `Alignment.topCenter`. Working code below:

```
body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: SizedBox(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.pink)),
                        height: 20.0,
                        width: 20.0,
                      )),
```

[image]

Hope this answers your question.